# Unable to boot into Ubuntu after Windows 10 reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, grub

After reinstalling Windows 10, I am now unable to boot into Ubuntu 22.04.

- The message displayed right after the boot failure is:

  [image: screenshot of error message]
- Right afterwards, I entered maintenance mode and typed `journalctl -xb` as suggested by the terminal. Here is the full output: https://pastebin.com/T00shLGu.

  - **NOTE:** The lines beginning with `>>`  represent lines colored in **red** in the original output
- Here are just those lines that were in red:

  ```
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - ^SPI1.SPFD.CVFD (20210730/dspkginit-438)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - ^SPI1.SPFD.CVFD (20210730/dspkginit-438)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - ^XHCI.RHUB.HS04.VI2C (20210730/dspkginit-438)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - ^XHCI.RHUB.HS04.VI2C (20210730/dspkginit-438)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: pnp 00:05: disabling [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] because it overlaps 0000:00:02.0 BAR 9 [mem 0x00000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0xfedc0000-0xfedcdfff], which spans more than pnp 00:05 [mem 0xfedc0000-0xfedc7fff]
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: caller tgl_uncore_imc_freerunning_init_box+0xb5/0xf0 mapping multiple BARs
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: i8042: Warning: Keylock active
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: acpi PNP0C14:01: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: WQBC data block query control method not found
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: acpi PNP0C14:05: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: acpi PNP0C14:06: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: pci 10000:e0:1c.4: Primary bus is hard wired to 0
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: pci 10000:e0:1c.4: Primary bus is hard wired to 0
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: pcieport 10000:e0:1c.4: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: pcieport 10000:e0:1c.4: PCI INT A: no GSI
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: usb: port power management may be unreliable
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: ahci 10000:e0:17.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: ahci 10000:e0:17.0: PCI INT A: no GSI
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] Initialising logging on level 5
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] Atomic driver: yes
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_platform_add_devices:158 Increasing device count to 4
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_crtc_init:498 drm_crtc_init: 0 p00000000e5d384fe
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 407 (systemd-modules) of process 407 (systemd-modules)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi evdi.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [W] evdi_painter_send_update_ready_if_needed:693 Painter does not exist!
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: [drm] Initialized evdi 1.10.1 20220225 for evdi.0 on minor 1
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] Evdi platform_device create
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_crtc_init:498 drm_crtc_init: 0 p0000000078ff8a3d
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 407 (systemd-modules) of process 407 (systemd-modules)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi evdi.1: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [W] evdi_painter_send_update_ready_if_needed:693 Painter does not exist!
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: [drm] Initialized evdi 1.10.1 20220225 for evdi.1 on minor 2
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] Evdi platform_device create
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_crtc_init:498 drm_crtc_init: 0 p000000003f2b12e2
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Opened by Task 407 (systemd-modules) of process 407 (systemd-modules)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi evdi.2: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [W] evdi_painter_send_update_ready_if_needed:693 Painter does not exist!
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: [drm] Initialized evdi 1.10.1 20220225 for evdi.2 on minor 3
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] Evdi platform_device create
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_crtc_init:498 drm_crtc_init: 0 p00000000d8c83814
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Opened by Task 407 (systemd-modules) of process 407 (systemd-modules)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi evdi.3: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [W] evdi_painter_send_update_ready_if_needed:693 Painter does not exist!
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: [drm] Initialized evdi 1.10.1 20220225 for evdi.3 on minor 4
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] Evdi platform_device create
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:28 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan systemd-udevd[476]: nvme0n1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1' failed with exit code 1.
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan systemd-udevd[462]: nvme0n1p4: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p4' failed with exit code 1.
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan systemd-udevd[485]: nvme0n1p3: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p3' failed with exit code 1.
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan systemd-udevd[476]: nvme0n1p5: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p5' failed with exit code 1.
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan systemd-udevd[488]: nvme0n1p1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p1' failed with exit code 1.
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan systemd-udevd[478]: nvme0n1p2: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p2' failed with exit code 1.
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan systemd-udevd[473]: nvme0n1p6: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p6' failed with exit code 1.
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:29 ivan kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
  >> août 09 14:18:31 ivan kernel: usb usb2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
  >> août 09 14:18:31 ivan systemd-udevd[464]: sda: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda' failed with exit code 1.
  >> août 09 14:18:31 ivan kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
  >> août 09 14:18:36 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:36 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:36 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:36 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:36 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:36 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card3) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:36 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Opened by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:36 ivan kernel: evdi: [I] (card4) Closed by Task 304 (plymouthd) of process 304 (plymouthd)
  >> août 09 14:18:36 ivan kernel: usb usb2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
  >> août 09 14:18:40 ivan kernel: usb usb2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
  >> août 09 14:18:45 ivan kernel: usb usb2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
  >> août 09 14:18:49 ivan kernel: usb usb2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
  >> août 09 14:18:54 ivan kernel: usb usb2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
  >> août 09 14:18:54 ivan kernel: usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
  >> août 09 14:19:19 ivan kernel: usb 2-2.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=511), cval->res is probably wrong.
  >> août 09 14:19:19 ivan kernel: usb 2-2.2: [15] FU [USB Audio Device Playback Volume] ch = 6, val = -8176/0/16
  >> août 09 14:19:19 ivan kernel: usb 2-2.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=767), cval->res is probably wrong.
  >> août 09 14:19:19 ivan kernel: usb 2-2.2: [12] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 2, val = -4592/7680/16
  >> août 09 14:19:19 ivan kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
  >> août 09 14:19:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1038]: sda: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda' failed with exit code 1.
  >> août 09 14:19:20 ivan kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
  >> août 09 14:19:21 ivan systemd-udevd[1110]: sdb: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb' failed with exit code 1.
  >> août 09 14:19:58 ivan systemd[1]: dev-nvme0n1p7.device: Job dev-nvme0n1p7.device/start timed out.
  >> août 09 14:19:58 ivan systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/nvme0n1p7.
  >> août 09 14:19:58 ivan systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/share.
  >> août 09 14:19:58 ivan systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
  >> août 09 14:20:03 ivan kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun: transcoder,
  >> août 09 14:20:19 ivan systemd-udevd[1042]: 2-2.2:1.0: Spawned process '/opt/displaylink/udev.sh /dev usb-002-004-DisplayLink_Triple-display_Mini_Docking_station_D3A2836645952 /dev/bus/usb/002/004' [1061] is taking longer than 59s to complete
  >> août 09 14:20:19 ivan systemd-udevd[429]: 2-2.2:1.0: Worker [1042] processing SEQNUM=5036 is taking a long time
  >> août 09 14:22:19 ivan systemd-udevd[1042]: 2-2.2:1.0: Spawned process '/opt/displaylink/udev.sh /dev usb-002-004-DisplayLink_Triple-display_Mini_Docking_station_D3A2836645952 /dev/bus/usb/002/004' [1061] timed out after 2min 59s, killing
  >> août 09 14:22:19 ivan systemd-udevd[1042]: 2-2.2:1.0: Process '/opt/displaylink/udev.sh /dev usb-002-004-DisplayLink_Triple-display_Mini_Docking_station_D3A2836645952 /dev/bus/usb/002/004' terminated by signal KILL.
  >> août 09 14:22:19 ivan systemd-udevd[429]: 2-2.2:1.0: Worker [1042] processing SEQNUM=5036 killed
  >> août 09 14:22:19 ivan systemd-udevd[429]: Worker [1042] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
  >> août 09 14:22:19 ivan systemd-udevd[429]: 2-2.2:1.0: Worker [1042] failed
  >> août 09 14:22:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1110]: eth0: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-displaylink.rules:16 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.5/net/eth0/cdc_ncm/rx_max}, ignoring: Invalid argument
  >> août 09 14:22:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1110]: eth0: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-displaylink.rules:17 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.5/net/eth0/cdc_ncm/tx_max}, ignoring: Invalid argument
  >> août 09 14:22:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1110]: eth0: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 65536 > /sys/module/cdc_ncm/parameters/ntb_max_tx'' failed with exit code 2.
  >> août 09 14:22:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1110]: eth0: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 65536 > /sys/module/cdc_ncm/parameters/ntb_max_rx'' failed with exit code 2.
  >> août 09 14:22:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1058]: tx-0: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 65536 > /sys/module/cdc_ncm/parameters/ntb_max_tx'' failed with exit code 2.
  >> août 09 14:22:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1027]: rx-0: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 65536 > /sys/module/cdc_ncm/parameters/ntb_max_tx'' failed with exit code 2.
  >> août 09 14:22:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1058]: tx-0: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 65536 > /sys/module/cdc_ncm/parameters/ntb_max_rx'' failed with exit code 2.
  >> août 09 14:22:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1027]: rx-0: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 65536 > /sys/module/cdc_ncm/parameters/ntb_max_rx'' failed with exit code 2.
  >> août 09 14:22:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1027]: enx44a92c504d73: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-displaylink.rules:16 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.5/net/enx44a92c504d73/cdc_ncm/rx_max}, ignoring: Invalid argument
  >> août 09 14:22:20 ivan systemd-udevd[1027]: enx44a92c504d73: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-displaylink.rules:17 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.5/net/enx44a92c504d73/cdc_ncm/tx_max}, ignoring: Invalid argument
  ```
- Here are the partitions of the affected disk:

  ```
  Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
  Disk model: KBG40ZNS256G NVMe KIOXIA 256GB           
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: gpt
  Disk identifier: 4DA15AC7-2897-45BE-A63A-0F8A770F73AD

  Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
  /dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    514047    512000   250M EFI System
  /dev/nvme0n1p2    514048    776191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
  /dev/nvme0n1p3    776192 277256191 276480000 131.8G Microsoft basic data
  /dev/nvme0n1p4 277256192 462802943 185546752  88.5G Linux filesystem
  /dev/nvme0n1p5 462802944 498085887  35282944  16.8G Linux swap
  /dev/nvme0n1p6 498087936 500115455   2027520   990M Windows recovery environment
  ```

I'm really trying to figure this out and spent a good amount of time on it already, but I have no idea on how to solve that problem.

Any suggestion is welcome. Any question is welcome. If you need details, I'll get them.

## Additional information:

- I can boot fine into Windows 10
- I tried switching secure boot on and off, but it did nothing.
- While reinstalling Windows 10, I had to use downloaded drivers from Intel. Not sure if relevant, I can provide more details if needed.
- the main Linux partition is mountable and my files are still there and readable. It seems unaffected. I also have a full `dd` copy of the SSD before the Windows reinstall.

  - Here is a snapshot of the pre-reinstall SSD from a graphical partition manager: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZzqV.png
- The GRUB menu shows up like expected. I did a GRUB reinstall with `boot-repair`, following the "recommended repair" route. However I don't know if it actually did anything. Before that "repair" I was actually able to access the GRUB menu and start booting on Ubuntu. However, upon encountering the boot failure described in this post, I assume GRUB was messed up and tried to repair it.
- Concerning these `ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element`: I've had these error messages while I was still able to boot so it might not be the cause.
- I dont remember reading the `mtd device must be supplied` error before though.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem.
These error lines from the `journalctl -xb` output were the clue:

```
août 09 14:19:58 ivan systemd[1]: dev-nvme0n1p7.device: Job dev-nvme0n1p7.device/start timed out.
août 09 14:19:58 ivan systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/nvme0n1p7.
août 09 14:19:58 ivan systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/share.
août 09 14:19:58 ivan systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
```

After reading this I realized that there was no `/dev/nvme0n1p7` partition anymore since it was removed just before reinstalling Windows 10 (it used to be a data partition shared between Windows and Linux). Turns out that reinstalling Windows wasn't the cause of the problem.

I removed the following line from my `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p7    /mnt/share   ntfs   defaults    0 0
```

Lo and behold, I'm now writing this from my formerly inaccessible linux session.